# How to Catch and Handle Excel,IE,Winzip Closing Event in Java

Tags: java, excel, try-catch, handle

In my application, firstly, I upload xls, xlsx, zip file into database in binary format.

Secondly, I create a temp folder to load binary files and convert them to the original format in a temp folder, and open it automatically for users to have an overview.

However in security consideration, I hope to delete the temp files after the user close the excel or winzip application.

In my mind, I need to catch the closing event for the applications like excel and winzip then do the rest works.

I see some solutions by using C# or VB. I hope Java could also do the job. Could you give me some advises?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process.waitFor() to cause the thread that kicks off an external process to wait for it to complete.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

If you do not wish to block the main thread (as you should probably not do e.g. if this is a UI application), fire up a separate thread to perform external conversions.

Comment: Hi, Eric  Thanks for your answer. I notice that the document says "causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. " I wonder if user has already opened an excel file before running the application, when my application opens another new excel file, the process waited for is excel.exe, if I close one excel file, the process terminate all the two opening excel files, for they share the same process. Am I right? Kind of confusing about that. Thanks

Comment: Try the following experiment:  Click the Windows start button and type in Excel in the run bar.  Hit enter.  Repeat once.  Check out the task manager.  You have two separate Excel processes running, each with their own process ID.  If you launch Excel programatically, it will happen in a distinct process.  *However*, if you load an Excel document via a file association (e.g. double click an Excel file), Excel will load that document into a currently running Excel process if it can.

Comment: Hi Eric J. I got it. Thanks quite a lot for your help.